# What's the cleanest/ quickest way to get an attribute of object if it exists?

Tags: python

I want to get an attribute on an object if the object exists, otherwise set it to `None` or empty string or some default. Is there a quick one line way of doing this?

For example in pseudocode:

```
gender = if Person then Person.gender else ''
```

Comment: Funnily enough, your pseudocode is valid CoffeeScript and Coco. :)

Comment: Unrelated, but capitalized identifiers look like class names, not instances.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `default` parameter to `getattr()`:

```
gender = getattr(Person, "gender", "")
```

This will set `gender` to `Person.gender` if the `Person` object has such an attribute, and to `""` otherwise.

Comment: you test if the *attritbute* (`gender`) exists, but the question is about a missing *object* (`Person`).

Comment: @WolframH: If the name `Person` is defined, it points to some object, and that object obviously exists.  If that name isn't defined, my code won't work, yours neither.  I'm not really sure what you are talking about.

Comment: The differences show up, for example, if `Person` is an object of the wrong type. Another (probably far fetched) example would be an empty Person (`False` in a boolean context).

Comment: @WolframH: I know there are differences between my code and yours.  What I didn't get is what it is supposed to mean that the object named `Person` is missing.

Comment: Sorry if comment came over wronlgy. The OP's pseudo code lead me to believe that the OP can test for `Person`'s existence by truth value of `Person`. If that's wrong, I'm also wrong, obviously. My code is just a litte more along the line of thinking the OP had in mind, I believe. That doesn't mean your code is not excellent, though... :-)

Comment: @WolframH: Given the wording of the original post, your answer is certainly valid, but I think my take is also fine. :)  I took care to exactly explain what it does to avoid any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Person` has a `False` value if it doesn't exist:

```
gender = Person.gender if Person else ''
```